# Изменить labels в ModelForm

Tags: python, django

Что-то как-то в рунете информации немного по labels. Только на djbook про лэйблы нашел. Насколько я понял, Meta labels позволяет изменить содержимое тега  внутри генерируемой формы:

```
    class OneDayForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model = OneDay
       fields = ['WhatYouDo', 'Fillings', 'Events', 'Results']
       labels = {
           'WhatYouDo': ('Чего'),
       }
```

Но генерируется все равно со значением WhatYouDo

```html
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <label for="id_WhatYouDo">WhatYouDo:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
     <textarea name="WhatYouDo" id="id_WhatYouDo" rows="10" cols="40" required>
</textarea>
    </div>
```

Как это победить? 
PS: кстати на djbook в примере почему-то нижнее подчеркивание еще есть:

```
labels = {
    'name': _('Writer'),
}
```

У меня его pycharm подчеркивает красным цветом

Comment: Нижнее подчёркивание - это сокращение для функции gettext, которая используется для локализации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

просто уберайте скобки

```
labels = {
    'WhatYouDo': 'Чего',
}
```